# SendGrid delivery async not working on Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I've developed and application console to deliver email. This console application is performed by an Azure WebJob. I'm using DeliveryAsync method with Wait:

```
transportWeb.DeliverAsync(sendGridMessage).Wait();
```

But messages are not being delivered, they are not even shown in SendGrid dashboard. When I run the job in development environment (local) sending email works fine.

No exceptions are thrown, and I'm pretty sure that the problem is that the async task it's not completing.

I want to complete this without using [Web Jobs SDK Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions), is there any different approach?

Is there somethig else that must be configured on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your webjob function. It will display a string of the SendGrid response in your webjob dashboard "Toggle Output" window and you can diagnose the issue.

```
var response = transportWeb.DeliverAsync(sendGridMessage);
Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
```